# Minimum subgroup sample size

Tags: confidence-interval, sample-size, sample, computational-statistics

I have a population-level data set of continuous data, where a column represents a single individual and a row represents the measurement of the variable in question.

Given the scope of the data, I would like to test a hypothesis on only a subset and see how well it generalizes. Additionally, it is computationally taxing to work with this entire data set, especially as I write and test new code. However, when I build a subset, I want to ensure that I am controlling for a number of known variables: age, sex, race, level of education, etc. There are more than 40 in all.

My question: **How small can my subgroups be, such that I can maintain confidence that a group is largely representative of the population?**

Many thanks in advance.